# Java which element in the ListIterator is considered previous?

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I'm currently trying to learn how to implement my own ListIterators. I have most of it implemented and ready to go, except I'm confused by the previous() method. By standard convention, can I get an explanation of how previous() is usually interpreted.

i.e.:

```
             >cursor<
dog     cat    fish     bird     frog    snake
```

According to Oracles Java Platform 7 API:

E previous()

Returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position backwards. This method may be called repeatedly to iterate through the list backwards, or intermixed with calls to next() to go back and forth. (Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.)

What I don't quite understand is if previous() is called, does it return 'fish' or 'cat'.

I understand it in 2 ways:

1) 'fish' was the object that you were previously at

2) 'cat' is the object at the index numerically previous to the index of 'fish'

If previous returns 'fish', then does remove() actually remove the same element regardless of the direction of traversal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easiest to think of the cursor as being *between* two elements. So at the start, it's *before* `dog`. Calling `next()` returns `dog`, and moves it to between `dog` and `cat`, etc. You've finished iterating when the cursor is *after* `snake`.

So `next()` always returns the value after the cursor, and moves the cursor to the position after that. `previous()` always returns the value *before* the cursor, and moves the cursor to the position before that.

EDIT: As noted by David Conrad in comments: `remove()` always removes the last value that was returned by either `next()` or `previous()`. That's probably the least obvious part, when it comes to the way I've explained it above... it's much easier to model that behaviour using the sort of "on item" cursor you've described.

Comment: And `remove()` always removes the last value that was returned by either `next()` or `previous()`, to answer the point raised in the last sentence of the question.

Comment: Wow. That was a very simplistic, easy-to-understand answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DavidConrad: Thanks, I missed that bit. Will add it in.

Answer (score 1):

`ListIterator` is tricky, because the pointer's definition is a little bit different.

Java 7 documentation says:

> A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().

Possible cursor positions are (denoted by the asterisks):

```
*     *     *     *     *     *     *
  dog   cat  fish  bird  frog  snake
```

The `next` function advances the cursor by one position and returns the element between:

```
BEFORE:
*     *     v     *     *     *     *
  dog   cat  fish  bird  frog  snake
AFTER:
*     *     *     v     *     *     *
  dog   cat  FISH  bird  frog  snake
RETURNED: fish
```

The `previous` function will move the cursor back and will return the element between:

```
BEFORE:
*     *     *     *     *     v     *
  dog   cat  fish  bird  frog  snake
AFTER:
*     *     *     *     v     *     *
  dog   cat  fish  bird  FROG  snake
RETURNED: frog
```